# Is there any function or method in PHP that would be useful in determining the half of the month of the corresponding date?

Tags: php, function, loops, date, math

This technique is usually used in payroll system where in you have to determine if it is end of the month (usually, the 28th, 31st or 30th day of the month) and half of the month (15th day of the month). Is there any function to easily determine it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no ready made functions, but you can create conditions as needed, see example below:

Half of Month:

```
if(date('d') == 15){
    echo 'today is Half of the month';
}
```

End of Month:

```
if(date('d') == date('t')){
    echo 'today is end of month'
}
```

Additionally, would like to suggest you to go through with [Date Ref in PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) or [strtotime](http://php.net) to get that last day of the current month easily with something like...

```
new DateTime('last day of this month');
strtotime('last day of this month'); // alternatively
```

The first will give you a `DateTime` object like so...

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-07-31 05:03:37.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

And the second would give you an integer representing seconds from epoch `1438319031`

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this:

```
<?php
public static function get_days_of_month($month, $year, $half = 0) {
    if ($half) {
        $days = intval(trim(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year)));
        $days = floor($days / 2);
    } else {
        $days = intval(trim(cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year)));
    }

    return $days;
}
```

Comment: You will get the days for about a full month, or the days for about a half month.